# (userscript/tampermonkey) not allowing website to detect my mouse movement/clicks

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey

1. scenario = there is a website and as soon as i put my mouse inside the website it shows that i am online.
2. what i want to do = i want to bypass this i want to be able to put my mouse in  the website and copy and paste text while i am still seen as offline.
3. what i did = i am currently using tampermonkey with chrome with this userscript:

```html
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}, true);
```

4. the problem = it works i can put my mouse inside the website without it showing that i am online. but as soon as i click to copy a text it reveal my self as online.

is there another way where i can modify the userscript so i can copy and paste text without the website knowing i am online!? any solution would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You could try simply disabling javascript while you are doing this, that should prevent any and all scripts from ratting you out.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/BYOQskiuGU0

Alternately, you could try opening Developer Tools for the page, find the offending script and remove it.  should last until the page reloads.

alternately alternately, you could try simply viewing the source on the page.  if you're familiar with HTML you should be able to find the text in there and copy and paste as needed.